# MariaDB previous versions to handle a subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

Hello I have updated a function with a SQL query which works fine when testing in my development environment with MariaDB version **10.4.11**

I notice the production environment uses MariaDB version **10.0.38**

Is this version incapable of handling a simple subquery ?

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET issued_marker = 'on' 
WHERE COLUMN_ID = (SELECT COLUMN_ID FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_2_ID ='$id')
```

Comment: The query looks good, except one case: it will fail if subquery  return multiple rows.

Comment: thanks Slava, this might be the reason why the query is failing in production when it works in development which has a smaller test data

Comment: Change `COLUMN_ID = ` to `COLUMN_ID IN ` and you'll have a working query. Better yet, take the advice of @forpas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same with a self inner join:

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME t1
INNER JOIN TABLE_NAME t2 ON t1.COLUMN_ID = t2.COLUMN_ID AND t2.COLUMN_2_ID ='$id'
SET t1.issued_marker = 'on'
```

Comment: genius ! using this self inner join now worked in production without updating the version of MariaDB.    I don't understand why the database can handle INNER JOIN instead but it does work.  Thank you again.

Comment: This kind of update statement that uses the same table in a subquery does not work in MySql up until the latest version. It works in the latest versions of MariaDB but I can't remember if it worked in version 10.0.38. In any case the join is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks good, except one case: it will fail if subquery return multiple rows.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME 
SET issued_marker = 'on' 
WHERE COLUMN_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_ID FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_2_ID ='$id'
);
```

The above query will not fail on multiple subquery results, but update all matched rows.